# Python counting how many times numbers repeat in a random list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've generated a list of random numbers from 1-100, and I would like to count how many times there is a repetition.  for example `[1,2,2,3,3,3,4]` There is 1 extra 2 and 2 extra threes, so 3 repetitions. I would like to achieve this without using any type of function.

Here is my attempt:

```
import random

counter = 0
compList = []
num = random.randint(0,100)

for i in range(0,100):
  comp_num = random.randint(0,100)
  compList.append(comp_num)

  print(compList)
  print(counter)
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the input mark, but I really need an answer on this one.

Comment: This isn't a "write the code for me" site.  Write some code, show your result, and show what you actually want.  Plus, it sounds like you just want someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: Ok i've updated the post with my code Mark.

Comment: Second of all, this isn't homework, i'm attempting to learn on my own.

Comment: When you run this, what do you get?  What do you actually want to get?  I ask because there are at least two errors that prevent it from even running.

Comment: All I get is the list of random numbers, which is fine. The only thing i"m struggling on is counting any kind of repetition.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't run.  And repetition of what?  If you had `[1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4]`, what result do you want? Two repetitions?  or the count of two 2s and four 3s?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Every time a number repeats, any number. The counter variable should be increased by one.

Comment: so again, what is the answer you want with my example?  4?  Because 2 is repeated once and 3 is repeated 3 more times for a total of 4?  Do you see why I asked to clarify your question?  It is completely unclear.  Give a *clear* example of what you want.  (and your code still doesn't run).

Comment: Yes that is exactly it.

Comment: So next time, include that kind of information in your questions.  give examples and explain how you want the result to look.  Also post code that can be cut-n-pasted and run.  Your example doesn't work and implies you manually typed it and didn't run it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply check that the number is in the list already before you add it.

```
import random

counter=0
compList=[]

for i in range(100): # don't need range(0,100)...zero is implied.
    comp_num=random.randint(0,100)
    if comp_num in compList: # if number is already in list count it as a repetition.
        counter += 1
    compList.append(comp_num)

# don't indent this under the for loop
print(sorted(compList)) # sorted so you can check the result.
print('repititions:',counter)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has really clarified my understanding.

Comment: @Daniel You're welcome.  On SO, give thanks by upvoting and/or selecting the answer that was most useful as the most helpful by checking the mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, I understand that you want a count of the elements of the list that equal a previous element. That equals the number of elements in the list minus the number of *distinct* elements in the list. If `compList` is your list after it is filled out, then you want

```
repetitions_count = len(compList) - len(set(compList))
```

since the `set()` includes only one copy of each value in the list.

In your example `compList = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4]`, the result is `3`, as desired.

By the way, there is another way to create your list that is faster, shorter, and more pythonic--namely, this oneliner:

```
compList = [random.randint(0,100) for v in range(0,100)]
```